# Вставка изображения в DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

Отлавливаю событие вставки изображения на элементе :

```
let el = document.getElementById("modalWnd");
el.onpaste = function (event) {
      alert("Ok");
}
```

Нажимаю PrtSc затем Ctrl+C. Все работает хорошо, если я предварительно щелкну мышью по элементу div с id="modalWnd". Событие вставки буфера обмена срабатывает.Но хочу, чтобы пользователю не надо было бы щелкать по div, чтобы фокус на нем устанавливался программно.

$("#modalWnd").focus() не дает эффекта. Не дает эффекта также $("#modalWnd").attr("tabindex", -1).focus()

Вроде бы элемент и так в фокусе, но el.onpaste все равно не срабатывает, пока не щелкнешь по нему мышью.

Кто-нибудь знает как решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let el = document.getElementById("modalWnd");
el.onpaste = function(event) {
  alert("Ok");
}
el.querySelector('input').focus();
```

```css
#modalWnd {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="modalWnd">
<input style="width:10px;margin-left:-15px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @vitaly-pos и у меня не input, а div

Comment: Да, я понял, поэтому свой коммент удалил. Спасибо!